# A word or a phrase that encompasses TV shows and movies

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to think my friend for always providing me with quality TV shows and movies. In my native language there is a single word that describes both of those things. What is the English word or phrase?

... for being a bottomless source of TV shows and movies?
... for being a bottomless source of quality television?
... for being a bottomless source of television entertainment?
... for being a bottomless source of visual entertainment?

Comment: Does your friend provided: DVDs; URLs; verbal suggestions?  Do you view them all on TV or do you sometimes go to see them at the movies?

Answer (score 2):

**Screen Arts**

> The primary goal of the Department of Screen Arts & Cultures is to provide students with first-rate instruction in the history, theory, aesthetics, and techniques of **moving image media** in their historical and emergent forms. –[lsa.umich.edu](https://www.lsa.umich.edu/sac/undergraduate/whyscreenartscultures)

Now, as for *"being a bottomless source of excellent viewing suggestions"*, I'm at a loss, other than to say, "My friend always sets me up with the best programing."

**programing**

> 2. *Radio and Television*. **the selection and scheduling of programs** for a particular period, station, or network. –[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/programming)

Answer (score 0):

[*Aficionado*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aficionado) sounds similar to what you're looking for.

> A person who is very knowledgeable and enthusiastic about an activity, subject, or pastime

It sounds like your friend is both *very knowledgeable* (quality shows) and *very enthusiastic* (providing you with them).

I don't know of any word that has that meaning in a visual-entertainment-specific way.

Comment: "Movie/film aficionado" is a great term to describe their friend.

Comment: This is exactly the English word you would be looking for without bearing any negative connotations that some other words might offer. Geek, nerd, or otaku can bear the positive connotation, but often come with a pejorative aspect.